# InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'object' requires a key to be defined

Tags: entity-framework

Entity-framework 7.

```
[Table("Settings")]
public class Setting
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public object DefaultValue { get; set; }
    public string Classification { get; set; }
    public FacilitySettingOverride FacilitySettingOverride { get; set; }
}

[Table("FacilitySettingOverride")]
public class FacilitySettingOverride
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("FacilityId")]
    public int FacilityId { get; set; }

    public object Value { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SettingId")]
    public int SettingId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Setting> Settings { get; set; }
}

[Table("Facilities")]
public class Facility
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public  virtual ICollection<FacilitySettingOverride> FacilitySettingOverrides { get; set; }
}
```

When run the code

```
 private IEnumerable<FacilitySettingOverride> GetFacilityBandwidthSettings
    {
        get
        {
            List<FacilitySettingOverride> settingList;
            using (SettingDbContext context = new SettingDbContext())
            {
                settingList = context.FacilitySettingOverride.ToList();
            }
            return settingList;
        }
    }
```

Then get the exception:

> InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'object' requires a key to be defined.

The context is:

```
public class SettingDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Setting> Settings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FacilitySettingOverride> FacilitySettingOverride { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=13.53.63.74;Initial Catalog=AAAAA;User ID=sa;password=password);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }
}
```

However if I change the `object` to string for `Value` or `DefaultValue` in POCO then no exception. But the type in the database is `sql_variant`. I have to use the type `object`.

Comment: I don't think `sql_variant` is supported by Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Data annotations are not yet supported so you will need to use the Fluent API for configuration.

See: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1913#issuecomment-86662854